# YouTube API with Google PHP SDK - Response as JSON

Tags: php, json, youtube, youtube-data-api

For my latest Project I would need the result from a YouTube Search as a JSON string. I have tried to modify the code of the official Samples from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=de) so that the whole response array is returned as JSON but the JSON output only includes one result and only two tags of that result

> {"etag":"\"bvxF-DWHx1toJotsdJBeCm43SLs/Ti9GPWl-tTk2fzo_W4M7px11bPY\"","eventId":null,"kind":"youtube#searchListResponse","nextPageToken":"CBkQAA","prevPageToken":null,"visitorId":null}

And thats my code:

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: application/json');
if ($_GET['q'] && $_GET['maxResults']) {
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
$DEVELOPER_KEY = 'not gonna reveal my key ;) ';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
try 
{
    $searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
        'q' => $_GET['q'],
        'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
    ));
    print_r(json_encode($searchResponse));
} 
catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
    htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
} 
catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
    htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
    }
}
?>
```

In the end I would love to have something like

```
    {
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"bvxF-DWHx1toJotsdJBeCm43SLs/vL7IQMNuL84nujDqKdOtwOPpBkc\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAIQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 203164,
  "resultsPerPage": 2
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"bvxF-DWHx1toJotsdJBeCm43SLs/m4lAJ1Qx-hvZpw4Uc9qSo_rqy5o\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "UyI4v5sxT54"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-04-14T10:21:21.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCpDJl2EmP7Oh90Vylx0dZtA",
    "title": "BORGORE & SIKDOPE - Unicorn Zombie Apocalypse (Original Mix)",
    "description": "BORGORE teams up with SIKDOPE to bring you the main stage rocker that is Unicorn Zombie Apocalypse. Grab your copy NOW : http://btprt.dj/1hFUQhP ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UyI4v5sxT54/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UyI4v5sxT54/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/UyI4v5sxT54/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "SpinninRec",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"bvxF-DWHx1toJotsdJBeCm43SLs/4LQaEODdVEec6exNA21SnYJAeOU\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "CPXv392pc9k"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-05-16T23:00:00.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCpDJl2EmP7Oh90Vylx0dZtA",
    "title": "Borgore & Sikdope - Unicorn Zombie Apocalypse (Official Music Video)",
    "description": "Borgore & Sikdope present Unicorn Zombie Apocalypse (Official Music Video). Download your copy on Beatport HERE : http://btprt.dj/1hFUQhP English ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CPXv392pc9k/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CPXv392pc9k/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CPXv392pc9k/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "SpinninRec",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Are you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to JSON-encode the Response Object that you received while using the php client library. It is NOT the raw JSON object that the Youtube API returned (and what you want to encode).

If you `var_dump($searchResponse);` you'll see it says `Google_Service_YouTube_SearchListResponse Object`

You want to json_encode the "simpleObject" that you get by calling `toSimpleObject` on the model like:

```
json_encode($searchResponse->toSimpleObject());
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution is the only one to access protected methods from the response api...

Comment: I really wonder at one of two things: why this information on their documentation is not the first result when searching google, or why am I so bad at reading said documentation.